# Tkinter canvas scrollbar greyed out

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried following a few tutorials for how to get a canvas to scroll however it always ends up being greyed out. I tried adding a scrollregion to the canvas but I didn't understand it and only got as far as it not being greyed out but doing still nothing.

My code (After running resize it to be shorter vertically and it'll still be greyed out):

```py
self.main_window = Tk()
        self.root = Frame(self.main_window, bg="white")
        self.root.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # TOP SECTION
        self.top = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
        self.top.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        Label(self.top, text="#########################################").pack()

        # BOTTOM SECTION
        self.bottom = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
        self.bottom.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # BOTTOM-LEFT SECTION
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.bottom, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT)
        self.left = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.left.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        left_scroll = Scrollbar(self.left, orient=VERTICAL)
        left_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        left_scroll.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=left_scroll.set)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\", topdown=True):
            full = dirs + files
            for i in full:
                Button(self.left, text=i, bg="white", anchor="w", relief=SOLID, borderwidth=0).pack(fill=BOTH)
            break

        # BOTTOM-RIGHT SECTION
        self.right = Frame(self.bottom, bg="white")
        self.right.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=RIGHT)
        Label(self.right, text="##########################").pack()
        Label(self.right, text="##########################").pack()

        self.main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please make this to a minimal example that we can just copy and paste, to see what happens there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `pack()` to put the frame `self.left` into the `self.canvas`, use `self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.left, anchor='nw')` instead.

Also you should not put the scrollbar into the frame `self.left`, put it into the frame `self.bottom` instead and pack it to side `LEFT`.

Finally you need to update `scrollregion` of `self.canvas` in order to make the scrollbar work.

Below is the modified code based on yours:

```
    self.main_window = Tk()
    self.root = Frame(self.main_window, bg="white")
    self.root.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    # TOP SECTION
    self.top = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
    self.top.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    Label(self.top, text="#########################################").pack()

    # BOTTOM SECTION
    self.bottom = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
    self.bottom.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    # BOTTOM-LEFT SECTION
    self.canvas = Canvas(self.bottom, bg="white")
    self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT)
    self.left = Frame(self.canvas)
    #self.left.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self.left, anchor='nw') ###
    left_scroll = Scrollbar(self.bottom, orient=VERTICAL) ### self.left to self.bottom
    left_scroll.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y) ### side=RIGHT to side=LEFT
    left_scroll.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=left_scroll.set)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\", topdown=True):
        full = dirs + files
        for i in full:
            Button(self.left, text=i, bg="white", anchor="w", relief=SOLID, borderwidth=0).pack(fill=BOTH)
        break
    ### update scrollregion of self.canvas
    self.left.update()
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'))

    # BOTTOM-RIGHT SECTION
    self.right = Frame(self.bottom, bg="white")
    self.right.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=RIGHT)
    Label(self.right, text="##########################").pack()
    Label(self.right, text="##########################").pack()

    self.main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Before the for loop.

Comment: Sorry, didnt saw it.