# Tkinter scrollbar is not executing scroll action on canvas python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

I have the following code:

```
tabControl = Notebook(root)

tab0 = Frame(tabControl)
tab0.pack(fill="both")
tabControl.add(tab0, text="Wardrobe")
tab1 = Frame(tabControl)
tab1.pack(fill='both')
tabControl.add(tab1, text='Weapons', state='normal')
tab2 = Frame(tabControl)
tab2.pack(fill='both')
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Ammo', state='normal')

tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

# determine canvas
w = 1000
h = 1500

canvas = Canvas(tab0, width=w, height=h, relief='ridge', scrollregion=(0, 0, w, h), highlightthickness=0)

sbar = Scrollbar(tab0, orient=VERTICAL)
sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
sbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(width=w, height=h)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, expand=True, fill=BOTH)

# WARDROBE
# photos
planep = PhotoImage(file='images/plane pic.png')
plane = Label(canvas, image=planep)
plane.pack()
plane.place(relx=0.3, y=100, anchor='center')
```

I managed to get the scrollbar moving but when I "scroll" nothing really happens on the screen except the scrollbar moving (image labels are staying in the same place all the time). I also added an example of adding an image label to it since I think the problem lies in determining `y=100` in placing the plane picture.
Does anyone have an idea what should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216149/tkinter-canvas-scrollbar-greyed-out

Comment: You can simply replace the last three lines by `canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=planep, anchor='nw')` and set the height of canvas less than `h`.

Comment: I first tried out the solution provided by @acw1668, since it was the most straight-forward one. It worked immediately, so thank you. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the problem was me not drawing images onto canvas but on the tab0 instead. This has resulted in an illusion that the canvas isn't moving although it was, right?

Comment: Yes, sort of.  You should use `canvas.create_xxxxxx()` functions to put objects into canvas.